# QGIS doesn't keep the WMS updated

Tags: qgis, wms

I am trying to use the WMS and WMTS services of the Civil Protection Department weather radar:
https://dpc-radar.readthedocs.io/it/latest/services.html
However, in QGIS 3.18 it is not known that the images are not updated when they should do it every 5 minutes as per web viewer:
[http: //www.protezionecivile.gov.it/radar-dpc /](http://http:%20//www.protezionecivile.gov.it/radar-dpc%20/)
With F5 nothing happens and I also tried not to set the use of caching in display.
I tried with this code without success

```
from qgis.core import QgsProject
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('vmi')[0]
layer.dataProvider().reloadData()
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

Comment: Maybe add a button so you can update manually.

Comment: the problem is that i can't find the way to update the wms

Comment: Delete the layer and recreate it.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a "Reload layer" option too, and neither deleting/recreating the layer nor disabling the cache worked. I was finally able to reload the tiles of the WMS by right-clicking on the layer, going on "**Change Data Source**", and then just selecting the same source again. I hope this helps someone stumbling across this.

Comment: This sounds like a potential feature request for QGIS if it has not yet been implemented.